# Why does python mysql connector insert apostrophes into from clause in execute()?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm trying to insert a variable into a sql select query's from clause using Python and mysql-connector. However, it appears execute() is adding apostrophes around the variable name. Why is this happening, and what can I do to stop it?

I have no problem inserting variables in the where clause.

My code:

```
import mysql.connector
import sys

password = sys.argv[1]
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password=password, database='arch')
cursor = conn.cursor()

tables = ['A', 'B', 'C']
for table in tables:
    query = 'SELECT * FROM %s'
    cursor.execute(query, [table])
    results = cursor.fetchall()
    print(results)
```

results in the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "smoke.py", line 11, in <module>
    cursor.execute(query, [table])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 515, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 488, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''A'' at line 1
```

Please note the two single quotes on either side of the table name in the traceback.

When I do "SELECT * FROM A" straight into the mysql interpreter, I have no problems running that query.

Comment: Did you tried to remove the brackets around table at execute line?

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't help. execute() expects a tuple or list when inserting variables into a query.